# memory structure of a vector<T>

Tags: c++, memory, stdvector

I am playing around with vectors in c++ and I've tried to figure out how a vector looks inside memory...

I made a vector like this: `vector<int> numbers = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };` and extracted a couple of information about the vector

---

`&numbers`: 002EF8B8

`begin()._Ptr`: 0031A538

`end()._Ptr`: 0031A550

---

data at vector memory location 002EF8B8 :

00 9d `31 00 38 a5` `31 00 50 a5` 31 00 50 a5 31 00
cc cc cc cc 30 31 82 1f

found `begin()._Ptr` and `end()._Ptr` addresses stored there...

---

and integers found in that address range:

1st int at memory location: 0031A538 = `01 00 00 00`

2nd int at memory location: 0031A53C = `02 00 00 00`

3rd int at memory location: 0031A540 = `03 00 00 00`

4th int at memory location: 0031A544 = `04 00 00 00`

5th int at memory location: 0031A548 = `05 00 00 00`

6th int at memory location: 0031A54C = `06 00 00 00`

---

### Question:

If `002EF8B8` is the memory location of the vector, `31 00 38 a5` and `31 00 50 a5` are beginning and the end of vector, what is `00 9d` at the beginning and the data after? `31 00 50 a5 31 00 cc cc cc cc 30 31 82 1f`

I got the size with `numbers.size()*sizeof(int)` but I'm almost sure that's not the actual size of vector in memory.

**Can someone explain to me how can I get the size of actual vector, and what does each part of it represent?**

something like:

data size `[2 bytes]` `[4 bytes]` `[4 bytes]` `[? bytes]`

data meaning `[something]` `[begin]` `[end]` `[something else]`

---

EDIT:
bcrist suggested the use of `/d1reportAllClassLayout` and it generated this output

```
1>  class ?$_Vector_val@U?$_Simple_types@H@std@@    size(16):
1>      +---
1>      | +--- (base class _Container_base12)
1>   0  | | _Myproxy
1>      | +---
1>   4  | _Myfirst
1>   8  | _Mylast
1>  12  | _Myend
1>      +---
```

which is basically `[_Myproxy]` `[_Myfirst]` `[_Mylast]` `[_Myend]`

Comment: You do realize that you can read the complete source code of `vector` template in `<vector>` header, right? You are taking a rather roundabout route on your quest to enlightening.

Comment: apart from storing begin and end, the only thing a vector need to store is capacity and pointer to the allocator

Comment: The size of the object `numbers` in memory is, of course `sizeof(numbers)`. Not to be confused with the size of the heap-allocated block of data that a pointer stored within `numbers` may point to.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thanks... I've missed that :) just started to work in c++ and I still in learning more... but in combination with Andrey Chernyakhovskiy's answer... I've figured it out

Comment: include: what compiler you're using and what `sizeof numbers` is

Comment: If you're using VC++ (`_Ptr` looks like Dinkumware's style) you can use the undocumented compiler options `/d1reportAllClassLayout` or `/d1reportSingleClassLayout` to see the memory-layout of a class or struct.  Details [here](http://ofekshilon.com/2010/11/07/d1reportallclasslayout-dumping-object-memory-layout/).

Comment: @Ubica glad it helped.  In release builds, `sizeof(_Container_base12) == 0`.  I believe it's mainly used in checking for iterator misuse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You misinterpret the bytes. On a little-endian machine, the value 0x0031A538 is represented with the sequence of bytes 38 A5 31 00. So, your highlights are shifted.

Actually you have four addresses here: 0x00319D00, 0x0031A538, 0x0031A550 and again 0x0031A550.

A vector minimally needs three values to control its data, one of them being, obviously, the vector base. The other two may be either pointers to the end of vector and the end of allocated area, or sizes.

0x0031A538 is obviously the vector base, 0x0031A550 is both its end and the end of allocated area. What still needs explanation, then, is the value 0x00319D00.

Comment: 0x00319D00 indeed is the only mystery left, but I'll try to figure it out from the source code... Thanks

Comment: `cc cc cc cc 30 31 82 1f` also needs explanation. (if `sizeof numbers == 16` that would explain it, but if not then it wouldn't)

Comment: @MattMcNabb, my guess is that that's some debug helper object. Allocators must theoretically be stateless and take no space. As to `cc cc cc cc`, it is clearly not part of the `vector` object. Some compilers use the `cc` byte to fill uninitialized data in debug mode.

Comment: On dinkumware64 the vector has 4 members, `_Myfirst`, `_Mylast`, `_Myend` and `_Alval`.  I think the last one is a class with no member variables that represents the allocator (but final classes can't have size zero so it must have size at least one, and so the size is rounded up to the alignment requirement of the struct containing it)

Comment: on another implementation I use the `vector` has 8 pointers in it; the other 4 store a linked list of active iterators into the vector, this is used for iterator debugging

Comment: The allocator is stateless, but it contains a value on this implementation (which is set to 1)